# onCreate not call for startService - Native-modules

Tags: android, react-native, android-service, foreground-service, react-native-native-module

I use react-native modules.

I create a java class that extend service to create a foreground notification.
Inside my primary module java class i try to start service with :

```
getReactApplicationContext()
                .startService(
                  new Intent(
                    getReactApplicationContext(),
                    ForegroundService.class
                  )
                );
```

In android documentation it should call

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
```

inside my ForegroundService class.

No error are throwing so i believe the service is started without any errors.
But this onCreate method is never call.
I add `<service android:name="com.mediarecorder.ForegroundService"/>` already.

Thanks for helping.

I try different context and try to find any solution but no one fit to my question.